# TypeError: Network request failed Upload Image Firebase React native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I try to upload an image to firebase by using React native. But I get an error when I try to upload the image:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
```

I have use this code two times before and it works then. The different this time is that I use React native cli and not Expo. Also that this time the image is printscreen of an previous screen and not a picked one from the libary by using react-native-image-picker.

My code:

```
  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const uri = props.route.params.result;
    const childPath = `paintBoards/${
      auth().currentUser.uid
    }/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;
    console.log(childPath);
    console.log(uri);
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const task = storage().ref().child(childPath).put(blob);

    const taskProgress = snapshot => {
      console.log(`transferred: ${snapshot.bytesTransferred}`);
    };

    const taskCompleted = () => {
      task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(snapshot => {
        savePostData(snapshot);
        console.log(snapshot);
      });
    };

    const taskError = snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot);
    };

    task.on('state_changed', taskProgress, taskError, taskCompleted);
  };

  const savePostData = downloadURL => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('PaintBoards')
      .doc(auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection('UserPaintBoards')
      .add({
        downloadURL,
        caption,
        creation: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      })
      .then(function () {
        props.navigation.popToTop();
      });
  }
```

Comment: Does the app have Internet access? Expo sets the corresponding permission automatically. [Check Android Permission here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid)

Comment: Yes, the  app has internet, but is maybe not best. but I can create a new user and add data to Firestore etc.

Comment: Du you now if I have to add any dependency for blob? @Lukas